# vba add shape, wait 3 seconds then delete

Tags: excel, image, vba

I am trying to add an image to a spreadsheet by using the following code.

```
    Sub InsertPic()

    Dim pic As String 'file path of pic
    Dim myPicture As Picture 'embedded pic
    Dim rng As Range 'range over which we will iterate
    Dim cl As Range 'iterator

    Set rng = Range("C5")  '<~~ Modify this range as needed. Assumes image link URL in column A.
    For Each cl In rng
    pic = "https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/167549/Kliponious-green-tick.png"

        Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)
        '
        'you can play with this to manipulate the size & position of the picture.
        ' currently this shrinks the picture to fit inside the cell.
        With myPicture
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 40
            .Height = cl.Height
            .Top = Rows(cl.row).Top - 2
            .Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left + 10
        End With
        '

     Next

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

With myPicture
.delete
End With

     End Sub
```

After a 3 second delay, i want to delete the image.

For some reason, vba will not wait and deletes the image straight away.

Please can someone show me what i am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Just for quick troubleshoot - try changing it to 1 minute. Does it still not delay? If not, step through the code (using `F8`) and see if that line gets skipped over for some reason.

Comment: Try `CDate("00:00:03")` instead of `TimeValue`.  Just a guess.  I always use CDate.

Comment: Try `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)` instead.  It isn't effected by regional settings.

Comment: @BruceWayne yes same problem occurs. For some reason the image is either not being inserted or is being deleted straight away and then the application just waits however long i set the timer delay

Comment: Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) didn't seem to work either

Comment: If you step through your code, does it skip the `Wait` line and go straight to `With myPicture`?

Comment: For what it's worth - I used your exact code in my Excel (2016), and it paused for the alotted time...It didn't immediately delete the image. What version of Excel are you using? (I'm glad you found a solution, I'm just curious as to why your time is skipping). Can you make a super simple macro that just puts a cell value in `C5`, then deletes that value after say, 10 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, `Application.OnTime` takes a second argument which is the code subroutine to call.

So you need

```
Sub Sub1()
 'Insert pic
  Application.OnTime now()+CDate("00:00:03"), "Sub2"
End Sub

Sub Sub2()
  'delete pic
End Sub
```

I know you want to use `Application.Wait` but it maybe that you have to yield back to the message queue.

Comment: @S Meaden thanks this seems to be working, however now my picture won't delete. No error, just won't delete. Is .delete the correct function to be using?

Comment: Use your existing code to delete the image but stored reference in a module level variable.